# Strapi - How to allow author role to publish their contents?

Tags: next.js, strapi

I try Strapi to build a marketplace with a SuperAdmin user. SuperAdmin can create users (sellers) of role "author". Sellers can then manage (CRUD) their contents (products). But now the sellers cannot publish the contents while publishing authorization is on "editor" role by default in Strapi. In my case, I do not need to have editor role. The idea is that the "Seller A" should not see contents of "Seller B".

Answer (score 0):

Your seller role can be a standard Authenticated role.

[image: standard Authenticated]

Then you will need to limit *Seller A* in the front-end.

While listing sales in the front-end, check if the sale belongs to the seller.

[image: add to many]

[image: permissions]

Comment: What do you mean by "a standard Authenticated role"? You mean "author" or "editor" or else?

Comment: Authenticated user role